# How to style recently viewed products horizontally

Tags: xml, css, custom, static-block, widgets

I've just recently moved my recently viewed products to just below my product detail page and above the header. However, the items show up vertical and I'd like them to be horizontal. Is there a proper way of styling this (for example with css) so I don't have to touch any base/core files? Using CSS, I can't seem to find out what exactly to style. Edit: Code added, not sure what this could add but anyway here it is.

```
   <reference name="right">
         <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>right.reports.product.viewed</name>
         </action>

    <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />

<catalog_product_view>

   <reference name="content">
   <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="my.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
   </reference>

 </catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Please show your code.